# What's the difference between Clang and SourceKit?

Tags: clang

I'm studying about SourceKit, which is used in XCode.
Especially I got much from this webpage, http://www.jpsim.com/uncovering-sourcekit/ .
But there are still some what I couldn't recognized.

**What's the difference between Clang and SourceKit, or the relationship between them??**

Comment: I'd say it is pretty much stated in the first few paragraphs in the link you provide: sourcekit helps with creating the source code (syntax highlighting, autocompletion etc), but does not fully interpret the code so that you can actually use (run) it. Clang is the compiler that does the latter for you. SourceKit isn't really necessary to create a program (you can take a basic text editor, enter source code), but a compiler such as Clang is.

Comment: So perhaps you're asking about the difference between a (fancy) source code editor, and a compiler?

Comment: @Evert 
Oh I might get to recognize.
Both Clang and SourceKit can source code manipulation like syntax highlighting, autocompletion etc.
But Only Clang can compile souce code to LLVM IR.
Is this right?

Comment: Clang can't manipulate source code: Clang (or any compiler) doesn't care about syntax highlighting: it takes the bare (ASCII, Unicode) characters and compiles that into code. It is (was or shortly will have been, according to your link) used to help syntax highlighting, since a compiler will barf at an error (incorrect syntax), and that can tell your editor to mark that part in red, for example. The compiler can generally be decoupled from your editor, and can run standalone.